# Jquery = setInterval code works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code (from an old plugin that I am trying to make responsive) slides a set of images across every n seconds. It uses setInterval code as below, and works well on Firefox. On Chrome it runs once only, and debugging indicates that the second setInteral function is just not called. Please help as its diving me mad. Running example at   http://lelal.com/test/site10/index.html (sorry about the load time)

```
    play = setInterval(function() {
      if (!busy) {
        busy = true;
        updateCurrent(settings.direction);
        slide();
      }
    }, settings.speed);
```

The complete plugin code is below (sorry its long)

```
    /*
     * jQuery Queue Slider v1.0
     * http://danielkorte.com
     *
     * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
     * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
     */

    (function($){
      var QueueSlider = function(element, options) {

        var play = false,
            busy = false,
            current = 2,
            previous = 2,
            widths = [],
            slider = $(element),
            queue = $('ul.queue', slider),
            numImages = $('img', queue).size(),
            viewportWidth = slider.width(),
            settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.queueSlider.defaults, options);

        $(window).resize(function(){
            if(busy !== false)
            clearTimeout(busy);
            busy = setTimeout(resizewindow, 200); //200 is time in miliseconds    
        });

        function resizewindow() {
            viewportWidth = slider.width();
            if (settings.scale > 0) {
                slider.css('height',viewportWidth * settings.scale); 
                computeQueueWidth();
            }
            queue.css('left', -getQueuePosition());
            busy = false;
        }

        function requeue() {
          $('li', queue).each(function(key, value) {
            $(this).attr('class', 'slide-' + (key+1));
          });
        }

        function updateCurrent(dir) {
          current += dir;
          if (current < 1) {
            current = numImages;
          } else if (current > numImages) { 
            current = 1;
          }
        }

        function getQueuePosition() {
          var i = 0, index = current-1,
              queuePosition = (viewportWidth - widths[index]) / -2;

          for (i = 0; i < index; i++) { queuePosition += widths[i]; }

          return queuePosition;
        }

        function computeQueueWidth() {
            var     queueWidth = 0;
    //              factor = slider.height() / settings.imageheight;
    //      settings.imageheight = settings.imageheight * factor;
            // Get the image widths and set the queue width to their combined value.
             $('li', queue).each(function(key, value) {
                var slideimg = $("img", this),
                    slide = $(this),
    //              width = slide.width() * factor,
                    width = slideimg.width();
                slide.css('width', width+'px');
                queueWidth += widths[key] = width;
            });
            queue.css('width', queueWidth + 500);
        }

        function slide() {
          var animationSettings = {
            duration: settings.transitionSpeed,
            queue: false
          };

          // Emulate an infinte loop:
          // Bring the first image to the end.
          if (current === numImages) {
            var firstImage = $('li.slide-1', queue);

            widths.push(widths.shift());
            queue.css('left', queue.position().left + firstImage.width()).append(firstImage);
            requeue();
            current--; previous--;
          }
          // Bring the last image to the beginning.
          else if (current === 1) {
            var lastImage = $('li:last-child', queue);

            widths.unshift(widths.pop());
            queue.css('left', queue.position().left + -lastImage.width()).prepend(lastImage);
            requeue();
            current = 2; previous = 3;
          }

          // Fade in the current and out the previous images.
          if (settings.fade !== -1) {
            $('li.slide-'+current, queue).animate({opacity: 1}, animationSettings);
            $('li.slide-'+previous, queue).animate({opacity: settings.fade}, animationSettings);
          }

          // Animate the queue.
          animationSettings.complete = function() { busy = false; };
          queue.animate({ left: -getQueuePosition() }, animationSettings);

          previous = current;
        }

        //
        // Setup the QueueSlider!
        //
        if (numImages > 2) {

          // Move the last slide to the beginning of the queue so there is an image
          // on both sides of the current image.
        if (settings.scale > 0) {
            slider.css('height',viewportWidth * settings.scale); 
        }
        computeQueueWidth();
        widths.unshift(widths.pop());
        queue.css('left', -getQueuePosition()).prepend($('li:last-child', queue));
        requeue();

          // Fade out the images we aren't viewing.
        if (settings.fade !== -1) { $('li', queue).not('.slide-2').css('opacity', settings.fade); }

          // Include the buttons if enabled and assign a click event to them.
          if (settings.buttons) {
            slider.append('<button class="previous" rel="-1">' + settings.previous + '</button><button class="next" rel="1">' + settings.next + '</button>');
            $('button', slider).click(function() {
              if (!busy) {
                busy = true;
                updateCurrent(parseInt($(this).attr('rel'), 10));
                clearInterval(play);
                slide();
              }
              return false;
            });
          }

          // Start the slideshow if it is enabled.
          if (settings.speed !== 0) {
            play = setInterval(function() {
              if (!busy) {
                busy = true;
                updateCurrent(settings.direction);
                slide();
              }
            }, settings.speed);
          }
        }
        else {
          // There isn't enough images for the QueueSlider!
          // Let's disable the required CSS and show all one or two images ;)
          slider.removeClass('queueslider');
        }
      };

      $.fn.queueSlider = function(options) {
        return this.each(function(key, value) {
          var element = $(this);
          // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance.
          if (element.data('queueslider')) { return element.data('queueslider'); }
          // Pass options to plugin constructor.
          var queueslider = new QueueSlider(this, options);
          // Store plugin object in this element's data.
          element.data('queueslider', queueslider);
        });
      };

      $.fn.queueSlider.defaults = {
        scale: 0,
        imageheight: 500,
        fade: 0.3,              // Opacity of images not being viewed, use -1 to disable
        transitionSpeed: 700,   // in milliseconds, speed for fade and slide motion
        speed: 7000,            // in milliseconds, use 0 to disable slideshow
        direction: 1,           // 1 for images to slide to the left, -1 to silde to the right during slideshow
        buttons: true,          // Display Previous/Next buttons
        previous: 'Previous',   // Previous button text
        next: 'Next'            // Next button text
      };

    }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Is busy defined beforehand? This might be a case of handling undefined variables or different scope

Comment: The actual code on your web page uses `$play = setInterval(...)`, but that variable isn't defined anywhere, while it uses `clearInterval(play)`.

Comment: Chen - busy is defined at the top (busy = false)

Comment: Barmar - sorry my bad - I have now reverted to play and retested - still works in firefox and not in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

Looks like you're calling `clearInterval` after the first usage of `play`, which makes it stop working.

Comment: That's an interesting read, I had a hunch w3schools is not official. However, for the purpose of this question, it has the best given answer to quote from

Comment: jbkkd - thanks for that, but the only call to clearInterval is on a click function that is not pressed in the test - again same code works in Firefox not in Chrome??

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that part. Could you post a JSFiddle/JS Bin with an example of usage?